# error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 8)

Tags: git, github

I'm unable to push to github, and I've already tried changing the buffer or downgrading to HTTP/1.1 in git config. Here's the full command output:

```
PS C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\Website Projects\Voice-Rooms-Site> git push
Enumerating objects: 41, done.
Counting objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 4.37 MiB | 23.78 MiB/s, done.
Total 33 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 8)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I started when I tried to push a 5mb gif, and now even after removing that (with `git rm --cached`) I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Ok well I might have the problem, not sure yet... my upload speed is at < 0.01 mbps right now, could this be why

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was just my terrible upload speed.